# Como consertar: Object has no attribute, em python?

Tags: python

Sou novo em python e não entendo este erro de atributo que ele fala. Pra mim o código esta correto.

```
class Notebook:

    def __Init__(self):
    self.__notes = list()


    def storeNote(self,note):
    self.__notes.append(note)

a = Notebook()
print(a.storeNote(3))
```

O código esta exatamente assim no meu compilador.

segue um link pra voces verem o codigo em ação com o erro aparecendo.

https://repl.it/repls/DimgrayOutgoingGui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é um erro de digitação, você nomeou o construtor como:

```
__Init__
```

Quando deveria ser com letras minusculas:

```
__init__
```

Ou seja, sem o `__init__` o `self.__notes` não pode ser "declarado".

Veja que assim funciona https://repl.it/repls/WoodenConcreteObjectcode:

```
class Notebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__notes = list()


    def storeNote(self,note):
        self.__notes.append(note)


a = Notebook()
print(a.storeNote(3))
```

É importante notar que `storeNote` não retorna nada, logo o resultado no print vai ser `None`, poderia fazer algo como:

```
class Notebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__notes = list()


    def storeNote(self,note):
        self.__notes.append(note)


    def getNotes(self):
        return self.__notes


a = Notebook()
a.storeNote(3)
a.storeNote(4)
a.storeNote(10)
print(a.getNotes())
```

Ou até mesmo acessar diretamente o objeto (o que pessoalmente não gosto):

```
a = Notebook()
a.storeNote(3)
a.storeNote(4)
a.storeNote(10)
print(a.__notes)
```

---

Quero deixar claro também que `list()` se trata de uma função para converter alguns tipos específicos em lista, ou seja ele ali gerou uma lista para ti porque `list()` sempre retorna uma lista por "conveniência", mesmo que vazia, no caso como não passou o valor no parâmetro ele lhe deu uma lista vazia, mas você poderia simplesmente fazer isto `self.__notes = []`, assim:

```
class Notebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__notes = []


    def storeNote(self,note):
        self.__notes.append(note)


    def getNotes(self):
        return self.__notes
```